# Font tag appears on published page on its own

Tags: html, wordpress

In wordpress published pages `<font color="#FA8D03">` tag appears. I have checked my php files and wordpress pages also But that tag is not present in any of my created pages. Then why its showing up in published pages.

> UPDATED -: This is the code which I have chcked

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>  /*page.php starts*/
        <div class="banner-box">
        <?php while(have_posts()):the_post();
        ?><div class="wrap"><div class="main-top"><div class="main"><h1><div   class="titlepage"><?php the_title();?></div></h1><?php
        the_content(__('Continue_reading'));?><?php
        endwhile;
        ?></div></div></div><?php
        get_footer();?></div>
       /*page.php ends*/

        /*.....Header.php.....*/
        <?php if ( ! isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start(); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">   
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>
        <?php elegant_description(); ?>
        <?php elegant_keywords(); ?>
        <?php elegant_canonical(); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'et_head_meta' ); ?>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
            <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')?>/layout/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <?php $template_directory_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="<?php echo esc_url( $template_directory_uri . '/js/html5.js"' ); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <![endif]-->
                      <script type="text/javascript">
            document.documentElement.className = 'js';
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">

    #myCarousel .nav a small {
        display:block;
    }
    #myCarousel .nav {
        background:#eee;
    }
    #myCarousel .nav a {
        border-radius:0px;
    }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header-bg">
    <div class="wrap"><div class="container">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="sf-menu-top sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
                                <?php

    $defaults = array(
        'theme_location'  => '',
        'menu'            => 'menu_s',
        'container'       => 'ul',
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'sf-menu-top sf-js-enabled sf-arrows',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
    );

    wp_nav_menu($defaults );

    ?>                                                  
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook facustom"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter facustom"></i></a></li>                                                   
                            </ul>                     
                        </nav>
                    </div></div>
        <div class="wrap"> 
            <div class="total-box">
                    <div class="total">
                        <div class="header_top">
                            <div class="menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <?php

    $defaults = array(
        'theme_location'  => 'Primary Menu',
        'menu'            => 'menu_P',
        'container'       => 'ul',
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => '',
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''
    );

    wp_nav_menu($defaults );

    ?>                          
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="header-bottom">
                         <div class="logo">
                         <a href="index.html">दीन दयाल उपाध्याय कौशल केन्द्र </a><br /><a href="index.html">Deen Dayal Upadhaya Kaushal Kendra</a>
                                                    <h3>at Sanatan Dharma College(Lahore), Ambala Cantt</h3>
                                                    <font color=#FA8D03><em>--Aspire to Build Industry ready workforce</em> 
                         </div>
                        <div class="search">
                               <form>
                                    <input type="text" value="">
                                    <input type="submit" value="">
                              </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div> 
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    /*..........FOOTER.PHP.........*/
    <?php if ( 'on' == et_get_option( 'divi_back_to_top', 'false' ) ) : ?>

    <span class="et_pb_scroll_top et-pb-icon"></span>

<?php endif;?>



        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="copy-right">               
                        <div class="section group">
                            <div class="grid_1_of_5">
                                <div class="brand">
                                    <h1 class="brand_name">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <span>DDUKK</span><br />@ SD College(Lahore), Ambala Cantt
                                        </a>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                                <p class="copy">
                                    &copy; <span id="copyright-year">2015</span> |
                                    <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                                </p>
                                <p class="lastupdated">Last Updated on December 1, 2015</p>
                                <p class="lastupdated">Designed & Developed by <a href="#">Silex</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid_1_of_5"> 
 <h4>Important Links:</h4>                               
                                <ul class="list01">
                                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>                                   
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid_1_of_5">  
 <h4>&nbsp;</h4>                             
                                <ul class="list01">
                                    <li><a href="#">ERP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>   
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid_1_of_5">   
 <h4>&nbsp;</h4>                            
                                <ul class="list01">
                                    <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">College Map</a></li>                                  
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="grid_1_of_5">
                                <h4>Other Links:</h4>
                                <ul class="list01">
                                    <li><a href="#">KUK</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">SSC-Nasscom</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">NSDC</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
                    </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS --> <?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.nav li').first().addClass('active');    
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you've checked for the tag and the source code of the page showing the tag?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow! please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: looks like it was created by the wysiwyg

Comment: I havn't used wysiwyg. I have used only default editor.

Comment: Tried changing themes?

Comment: @j08691 - By changing theme I got rid of that tag. So its somewhere my code causing it, But where?

Comment: Have you looked at the functions.php for that theme?

Comment: @j08691 Yes I have checked that also. No problem in functions.php